# rspec not creating test models when generating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I've installed rspec through `rails g rspec:install`. ANd according to the documentation of rspec that would suffice to create models (`model_spec.rb`)

So I created a model right after `rails g model group name:string`. It creates a test_unit model but no rspec model. using `generate` instead of `g` didn't help either.

Here's my test-part of my gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14'
  gem 'fuubar'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-cucumber'
  gem 'rb-inotify', require: false
  gem 'rb-fsevent', require: false
  gem 'rb-fchange', require: false
  gem 'growl'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false 
end
```

Am I forgetting something perhaps?

Comment: Do you mean the model_spec.rb files aren't being created?

Comment: Yes. I'll rephrase my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the gem to the development group too.  According to the rspec-rails GitHub page:

> Add `rspec-rails` to both the `:development` and `:test` groups in the Gemfile:

[rspec-rails on GitHub](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails)

After that `bundle install` and `rails generate rspec:install`

Comment: adding it to `group :development, :test` did nothing to fix it I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah, got it. It's handy to save before you bundle... Your solution did the trick!